# white spots and something that looks like bugs

Tags: houseplants, plant-health

I just noticed this couple of days ago.
Any idea what it is and how to treat it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will they fly if disturbed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny enough I don't recognize what the insects are on your [Dracaena marginata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_(plant)) however I do know how to get rid of them.

- Add 5 ml of dish soap to a liter of water.  Your kitchen sink will do nicely.
- Take a dish cloth or disposable rag and soak in your soap solution
- wipe the whole plant down removing all the insects and the hard water stains on the leaves.  Rinse frequently
- wait a few minutes for the soap to kill the insects and then take it to the shower and hose it down to remove the soap solution
- repeat at five to six day intervals at least twice, more applications may be required

The insects are not spider mites or any species of mealy bug, scale or thrip that I recognize but they are soft bodied insects and soap will do the job.

Isolate the plant from other plants in case the insects spread, move to a higher light location and easy does it on the watering.  These plants are subject to root rot when stressed or in low light